# Python pandas.readexcel(filepath, header=[0,1]) fails when row 3 has data longer than header length. Any suggestion of fix is welcome

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have defined the first two rows ie 0,1 of my excel(xlsx) as headers. For simplicity the excel file has only one sheet. After the initial two rows there are few data rows in the file. Because of two headers pandas is giving me a multi-indexed data frame which is fine.

```
dataframe = pandas.readexcel(filepath, header=[0,1])
```

The above line gives me a valid dataframe whenever a file has all the rows upto the width of header.

Here is the problem. In one of my excel files i have 65 excel columns for the header rows and some data rows have 66 columns. pandas fails to execute

```
dataframe = pandas.readexcel(filepath, header=[0,1])
```

giving the error as

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 65 fields in line 3, saw 66
```

How to instruct pandas to read only 65 columns of the file? Setting `usecols` param as this

```
dataframe = pandas.readexcel(filepath, header=[0,1], usecols=65)
```

doesnt work may be because of multi-indexing.

Im using pandas 0.23.4, numpy 1.15.4, python 3.6.5

Here is a mockup data where first two rows ie headers have only 5 columns of data.
Whereas the row that has data for Apple has a extra column having value 10.

```
header1 header1   header1  2018 2019
id      brand     Model    qty  qty
1       Apple     iPhone    2    3    10
2       Samsung   Galaxy    2    5
```

Any ideas to restrict excel read only header length?

Comment: Can you post some mock of your data that replicates your problem so we can recover the error?  What does "a file [that] has all the rows upto the width of the header" mean - do you mean columns instead of rows?  Without this it's hard to help -- I guess for some reason you need all 66 columns to correctly parse rows [0, 1] into the appropriate `MultiIndex` but only 65 thereafter?  Is this because some cells are merged in a way that flows over the 65 rows of actual data?   Absent this, you could try just reading rows[2:] ignoring the headers and separately parse the `MultiIndex` afterwards.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using...I cannot replicate the issue with `0.23.4` using `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', headers=[0,1])`

Comment: @Chris Im using pandas 0.23.4, numpy 1.15.4, python 3.6.5

Comment: @arra I have added sample data above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally pandas manages to parse the file correctly. So it's a bit strange.

However, note that usecols is 0-indexed. Meaning that if you give it the value of 65, it will parse 0-65=66 columns, giving you the same error. (Although it should input a 66th column with unnamed header)

Can you try doing:

1. `dataframe = pandas.readexcel(filepath, header=[0,1], usecols=[64])`
2. `dataframe = pandas.readexcel(filepath, header=[0,1], range(0,65))`
3. adjust the range or list to smaller values and see if it still complains about the 66th column.